# Why the JS Event or CustomEvent doest not fire the first time on click after initial page load?

Tags: javascript, html, events

Im trying to figure out why the JS  event doest not trigger for the first time after the page load.

Here is a simple way to reproduce the scenario

**HTML**

```html
<button onclick="dispatch()">Test event</button>
```

**JS**

```js
function dispatch() {
  console.log('event');
  const eventTest = new Event('navbar:test');
  
 window.dispatchEvent(eventTest);
  
  window.addEventListener('navbar:test', (e) => {
    console.log('event was sent: ', e);
  }) 
  
}
```

[Live demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/billyjov/pen/OJpzQVJ)

Can someone pls explain the **WHY** of this behavior ? Is there a way to avoid this so that on the first click the event listener receive something using vanilla JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dispatching the `navbar:test` event before the event listener has actually been added for this event. It looks you may be expecting `dispatchEvent()` to fire the event asynchronously, but that is not what happens. The documentation says this:

> Dispatches an Event at the specified EventTarget, (synchronously)
> invoking the affected EventListeners in the appropriate order.

So just register the event listener before you dispatch the event:

```
window.addEventListener('navbar:test', (e) => {
  console.log('event was sent: ', e);
}) 
    
window.dispatchEvent(eventTest);
```

As a sidenote, note that with the way your code is currently constructed, you are adding a new event listener for `navbar:test` every time you click the button - is this really what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This was just for demonstration purpose.  I want to listen to the event in another url in my case.

So ... dispatch Event in page with url somesite.com/test and use eventlistener in another url somesite.com/test-event.

Comment: @billyjov that doesn't change the fact that `dispatchEvent` fires the event **synchronously**. If you can't add our listener before it's fired, your listener won't be able to catch it.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is bubbling.
When you add event to `window`, it blocks another events inside `window`.
You should add option `bubbles: true` when you creates custom event.

like here

```js
const eventTest = new Event('navbar:test', { bubbles: true });
```

* there also sometimes can be troubles when you touch button before script had been loaded and function `dispatch` had been saved into `window` object

Comment: Hi..But adding bubbles true doest not solve the issue

Comment: Did you use code from my answer? I'd changed it in your codepen before write it. Check it please, it should work